# How to automate configuration of legacy wireless drivers during installation

Tags: wireless, drivers, system-installation, bash, preseed

Perhaps the most common roadblock in deploying Linux on donated machinery is getting them to access the wireless network, due to the known issues with supporting legacy Broadcom drivers. Instead of manually checking the Ubuntu community support wiki pages to find the bash commands to get rare hardware drivers to work properly (for example, getting the MacBook Air to use WiFi: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookAir6-2/Saucy#Manual_installation_without_USB-Ethernet_Adapter), how could I customize Ubuntu installation to run my own script to install the wireless drivers relevant to the machine?

For example, if I know my donated hardware are Macs with Intel Processors, then the solution would launch as a stage during the installation to:

- perform a `grep` on `lshw -c network` (or something more efficient) to identify the make and model of the wireless adapter,
- then launch one of several bash scripts to automate the troubleshooting steps to install only the relevant drivers for that machine (which would have the dependent packages saved in advance on the installation media, so as to not require web access),
- and blacklist conflicting configurations (as needed).

This would solve one of the top frustrations of would-be Linux adopters (i.e., having to *go* online to figure out how to *get* online, only to learn that you *must* be online to `apt-get` certain packages), besides saving lots of time by automating the steps already proven by the global community to work successfully. Thank you.

Comment: Is there something wrong with running your script after installation? From a separate partition/drive/folder? And I always thought an ethernet network cable was standard equipment when trying to get new wireless equipment to work... What might be useful is a list of Ubuntu tested/supported WiFi hardware - does one exist?

Comment: I would like to experiment with `\preseed` as an appropriate stage to try improving the accuracy of the driver installation process, but I want to know how best to go about that. The problem with running scripts after the installation is that it slows down the ability to deploy Ubuntu on donated hardware substantially, especially when human resources are not available to have a full time system administrator to plug machines into an ethernet port in a server closet. Besides, once a laptop's connected to Wi-Fi and running a browser, new users like Linux - training can be kept to a minimum.

Comment: There are instructions for configuring hardware drivers on AskUbuntu, as well as on many well-established forums, such as the one I linked to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookAir6-2/Saucy#Manual_installation_without_USB-Ethernet_Adapter so the guesswork is only in how to automate such instructions. Hope that clarifies my inquiry.

Comment: @Xen2050: yes, here: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/

Comment: @Yaaqov: you're very vague on your preseed accomplishments so far; What is your specific problem?  Have you read the Debian developer documentation yet?  have you looked at custom Live CDs?

Comment: @Fabby, I'm not sure of the specifics of properly overriding or undoing default driver configurations in a bash script, but I'm sure others have, hence my post. If you are aware of specific documentation on scripting conditional installation of drivers based on hardware specifications picked up from `lshw`, please share. If it's appropriately detailed, post it as an answer, so I could give you credit.

Comment: I prefer to add comments when I'm unsure whether my crazy ideas are exactly what you're looking for.  Have a look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization) on how to create your own Ubuntu LiveCD.  And as Ubuntu itself is based on Debian, [This one](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianCustomCD) is a good one as well.  That will take you both 5 minutes (if not useful) to 30 minutes to read and know whether this is the way to go or not.

Comment: @Fabby, thanks for the references, and I'll see if customization of hardware configuration is covered. I'm still interested in similar efforts from other posters, though.